# Shop by category is missing when going to subcategory page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-list

I am developing a magento site where there is a left sidebar called "shop by category" by default in magento theme. I have created a category and there are some subcategories under parent category. When I go to parent category, it shows list of products as well as left sidebar with subcategories. But when I select subcategories, it shows list of products but left sidebar is missing. Is there any way to rectify it from admin or code level.

Comment: this is the default behaviour of magento. It will show categories in layered navigation section only  if the viewing current categories has child categories and the viewing category is set with `yes` for the field `is anchor`.

Comment: thanks to reply, I have not set "yes" for is anchor option for parent category too and it is listing "shop by category" and when I choose "yes" for is anchor option it does not show "shop by category" listing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Layout wise, magento distinguishes categories as `default categories` and `layered categories`. Magento uses `is anchor` option in order to make this categorization. If `is anchor` is set to `yes`, then that category would be `layered category` and if it is set to`no`, then that category will treat as a `default` catetgory.

**What happens when we set the property `is anchor` to yes ?**

Then the category will become a layered category. A category which holds layered navigation section along with it. Layered navigation will hold product attribute list which we set to include in layered in layered navigation so that we can filter products in a particular category using those product attriubte. `color` attribute is an example.

Another important thing about layered category - it will display all products not only from the selected category, but from its subcategories.

In this case, magento will process a unique layout handle `catalog_category_layered`.

**What happens when we set the proeprty `is anchor` to no ?**

Now these categories become default categories. Categories which will not show layered navigation section. So product attribute filtering is not possible for this type of categories.

Also a default category only show products which are assigned with that category itself. There is no possibility that it will show products that comes under its child categories.

In this case, Magento will process a unique layout handle `catalog_category_default`.

**What is the problem here ?**

You set all of your categories to default, coz `is anchor` property of all categories is set to no in your case.

There is very interesting point that I need to share with you in this case. If you take Magento's default theme (`base/default`), you can see that, layout handle for default categories `catalog_category_default` actually defines a left section. It looks like this.

File : `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
   ...
 </catalog_category_default>
```

This means it uses the block of type `catalog/navigation` in the `left` section. This block is actually responsible for the left content that you are viewing in a `default category`.

If you check inside `catalog_category_layered`, it uses another block of type `catalog/layer_view` to show the left section. So this block is obviously used to show the layered navigation section.

*So the question is what is `catalog/navigation` block does for default categories ?*

To answer the question, please have a look on the template file which is set with this block

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/navigation/left.phtml
```

You will find this line there.

```
 <?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
 <?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
```

It is clear that it collects all of its child categories and show as a link to filter. This means

***category filtering is always available in every category irrespective of the value set to the field `is anchor`***

So if you can see categories for a parent category and it seems empty for a child category, then that means the child category that you are describing actually does not hold any other child categories. At least this is the default case.

If the child category that you are referencing actually holds other child categories, then I am sure that some customization on the default behaviour is took place and you need to trace it out !!

Comment: In my categories page left navigation how can I order attributes? @Rajeev K Tomy

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Magento backend.Click on the Catalog > Manage Categories.
2. Click on the subcategory which is not showing the left navigation. then click on the "Display Settings".
3. Under Is Anchor select Yes and save.
4. Clear the cache and check